# How do I switch from _NewMailex to _NewMail in order to Step Into VBA Outlook code

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a program that works just fine regarding stepping through my E:Mails using the following :

```
Sub Application_NewMailex(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

Call MyRules
```

However, I am unable to Step Into this code to debug the logic, apparently because of the information inside the brackets.

Am I able to replace _NewMailex(blah blah blah) with _NewMail() and pick up / set the ByVal & EntryIDCollections in the code, as below ?

```
Sub Application_NewMail()

ByVal <<< how do I set this (what does it even mean ?!?)

EntryIDCollection As String <<< Can EntryIDCollection just be defined with my other Variables ?

Call MyRules
```

Any help appreciated, if it's not possible it's not a huge problem, it means I just have to send myself an E:Mail to trigger the routine every time I want to test it ...

Comment: See documentation on ByVal/ByRef : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/7363/passing-arguments-byref-or-byval#t=201702281244160240906

Comment: `NewMailEx` is an event, so the `EntryIDCollection` is passed to the handler by Outlook when it raises the event.  the `NewMail` event doesn't have any parameters, so Outlook doesn't pass it an `EntryIDCollection`.

Comment: R3uk - thanks I've read that and whilst I now see how ByVal/ByRef works, it seems utterly bizarre to my way of thinking (I was a COBOL programmer). I need to think a bit more about the EntryIDCollection and see why I put it in the first place !

niton - There are other processes after this that use the data that is created and updated by MyRules, they are the ones that I am debugging ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a question about how to debug. Place a break mark in your `NewMailex` sub. You can do this by highlighting the line you want to start your debugging on and pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>

Then go to the immediate window (you might need to find it on the *View* menu) and type this, replacing "EntryIdCollection" with a valid parameter value and then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
Application_NewMailex "EntryIdCollection"
```

Your code will run up to your break point and you can step through from there. If you don't know what a valid EntryIdCollection value looks like then just leave the break mark in and send yourself an email. You can see the value of EntryIdCollection in the locals (see below).

[image]

Comment: Thank you CallumDA, that has helped me (along with R3uK's comment above) ... I don't think I need the EntryIdCollection & I shouldn't need the ByVal parameter AFAIK, but the debugging will hopefully confirm that. 

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: No problem, `ByVal` isn't a parameter though -- it's a *method* of passing a parameter. Anyway, before you go it'd be great if you could mark this answer as accepted (tick mark to the left)